# Set compass points programatically with graphviz's cgraph library

Tags: c, graph, graphviz, dot

I'm creating graphs with the graphviz's cgraph library. For example, the following snippet of C code

```
Agraph_t *g = agopen("MyGraph", Agdirected, NULL);
Agnode_t *a = agnode(g, "A", TRUE);
Agnode_t *b = agnode(g, "B", TRUE);
Agedge_t *e = agedge(g, a, b, "", TRUE);
agwrite(g, stdout);
```

generates this dot graph

```
digraph MyGraph {
    A -> B;
}
```

which is rendered like this

```
(A)
 ↓
(B)
```

What I'd like to know is **how can I programmatically set the compass points** the edges must be anchored. The dot graph I'd like to get is:

```
digraph MyGraph {
    A:ne -> B:sw
}
```

which eventually could be rendered as

```
    (B)
   ↗
(A)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer by myself. This is what I needed:

```
agsafeset(e,"tailport","nw","");
agsafeset(e,"headport","se","");
```